# Is it possible to pause tick function for a specific child?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs

I hope you're well.

I'm working on a game at the moment, primarily for learning purposes, and have ran into a slight snag. I have a tick function running for an enemy, which controls it's movement and detects whether it interacts with the edges of the stage. If it reaches the edge of the stage then the angle changes and it moves off in another direction. Once this has happened a "bounceRate" decreases and once the bounceRate reaches 0 it disappears and a life is lost.

However, once the first enemy is removed the lives start to decrease constantly, rather than just the once. I have managed to "pause" the enemy tick function once the enemy bounceRate reaches 0 however the 2nd child doesn't appear on the stage once the first has been removed.

Here is the code in question:

**Global tick function**

```
function tick(event) {
    stage.update(event);
    for (enemy in enemyCamp) {
        var e = enemyCamp[enemy];
        e.tick(event);
    }
}
```

**Tick function for enemy**

```
enemy.tick = function(event) {
    if (!this.paused) {
        this.x += this.vX;
        this.y += this.vY;
        if (this.bounceRate <= 0) {
            if (this.x > canvasWidth || this.x < 0 || this.y > canvasHeight || this.y < 0) {
                var bounced = false;
                if(!bounced) {
                    bounced = true;
                    this.paused = true;
                    this.bouncedEnemy();
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (this.x > canvasWidth + 20) {
                this.angle = 180 - randomIntFromInterval(-90, 90);
                this.updateEnemy();
            }
            if (this.x < 20) {
                this.angle = 180 - randomIntFromInterval(90, 270);
                this.updateEnemy();
            }
            if (this.y > canvasHeight + 20) {
                this.angle = 360 - Math.floor(Math.random() * 180);
                this.updateEnemy();
            } 
            if (this.y < 20) {
                this.angle = 360 - randomIntFromInterval(180, 360);
                this.updateEnemy();
            }
        }
    }
    stage.update(event);
}
```

**Update enemy when reach edge of the stage**

```
enemy.updateEnemy = function() {
    this.bounceRate--;
    this.direction = this.angle * Math.PI / 180;
    this.rotation = this.angle;
    this.vX = Math.cos(this.direction) * this.speed;
    this.vY = Math.sin(this.direction) * this.speed;
}
```

**When enemy has "bounced"**

```
enemy.bouncedEnemy = function() {
    lives--;
    this.active = false;
    displayLives.text = "Lives " + Number(lives).toString();
    var displayedEnemys = enemyCamp.getNumChildren();
    enemyPen.removeChild(this);
    if ((displayedEnemys < level) || (displayedEnemys <= 0)) {
        spawnEnemy();
    }
    stage.update();
}
```

**Spawn enemy**

```
function spawnEnemy() {
    if (level > 1) {
        var w = 0;
        for (w;w<level;w++) {
            spawnRate++;
            enemyCamp[spawnRate] = new Enemy();
            enemyPen.addChild(enemyCamp[spawnRate]); //Enemy pen is a container
        }
    } else {
        spawnRate++;
        enemyCamp[spawnRate] = new Enemy();
        enemyPen.addChild(enemyCamp[spawnRate]);
    }
    stage.update();
}
```

At present the tick function runs once and then stops running once the child has been removed from the stage. `this.paused = false;` is called once the enemy has been created. Is there a way to pause the tick function for the child only, and then start again once a new child is added to the stage? That's what I feel is happening at the moment but I could be wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you don't show code where you would dispose of enemy having negative bounceRate, which seems important for your bug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Regarding the disposal of the enemy literally all I have is this line of code within the _bouncedEnemy_ function: `enemyCamp.removeChild(this);`

Here are the two variables for enemyCamp and enemyPen
`enemyPen = new createjs.Container();` and `enemyCamp = [];`

I have just noticed an error with my code above, I've adjusted it now. In the bouncedEnemy function it is actually set as `enemyPen.removeChild(this)`

Comment: you don't remove the enemy from the enemyCamp, but from enemyPen. But anyway what about sharing your codePen ?

Comment: I'll get a codePen thing set up asap for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the problem I was having. Upon inspecting my code I noticed a few things.

Firstly I moved my enemy Tick logic (working out bounces etc.) to the main tick function

```
function tick(event) {
    stage.update(event);
    for (enemy in enemyBeach) {
        var t = enemyBeach[enemy];
        e.tick(event);
        e.paused = false;
        if (!e.paused) {
            if (e.x > canvasWidth + 20) {
                e.angle = 180 - randomIntFromInterval(-90, 90);
                e.updateEnemy();
            }
            if (e.x < 20) {
                e.angle = 180 - randomIntFromInterval(90, 270);
                e.updateEnemy();
            }
            if (e.y > canvasHeight + 20) {
                e.angle = 360 - Math.floor(Math.random() * 180);
                e.updateEnemy();
            } 
            if (e.y < 20) {
                e.angle = 360 - randomIntFromInterval(180, 360);
                e.updateEnemy();
            }
            if (e.bounceRate <= 0) {
                if (e.x > canvasWidth + 20 || e.x < -20 || e.y > canvasHeight + 20 || e.y < -20) {
                    var bounced = false;
                    if(!bounced) {
                        bounced = true;
                        e.paused = true;
                        e.bouncedEnemy();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This worked to an extent but the lives were still dropping quicker than expected so I added the following to the bounced function. `if (this.active)`. Now lives were only dropping by one but the enemy wasn't spawning after this. I noticed that within my bounced function I was calculating the total of enemies on the screen before removing one. so the following if wasn't calculating correctly

```
if ((displayedEnemys < level) || (displayedEnemys <= 0)) {
    spawnEnemy();
}
```

The problem lies now where more enemies are in the stage but this initial issue is fixed for the time being.